# Flutter: Update icon widget based on whether a document exists in Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am designing an app to survey users on Current Affairs. I want a specific icon to appear based on whether the user has taken the Current Affairs survey or not.

At the moment, I have a future which pulls the name of the current survey from Firestore, and then checks whether a document exists within the collection *_entrants*. If the user has taken the survey, it will be stored in a document with a document name of their user id (which is gotten from Firebase Authentication).

If it does, the icon should be a tick icon, because the user has taken the survey. If they haven't taken the survey, the document will not exist and the user will see a another icon(like a 'New' icon), to show there's a new survey.

I have used the following code to do get the information on whether the user has taken the survey:

```
Future<void> takenSurvey2() async {
final sn = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('Controller')
    .document('Current Survey')
    .get();
surveyName = sn['cs'];
  //The above gives me the name of the current survey
final snapShot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
    .document(userid)
    .get();
if (snapShot.exists) {
  takenSurvey = true;
} else {
  takenSurvey = false;
}
setState(() {});
```

}

And then this is where the icon would be showed:

```
Positioned(
  right: 30,
  top: 20,
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: takenSurvey2(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (takenSurvey == false) {
        return Icon(
          Foundation.burst_new,
          size: 48,
          color: Color(0xff303841),
        );
      } else if (takenSurvey == true) {
        return Icon(
          Foundation.check,
          size: 48,
          color: Color(0xff303841),
        );
      } else
        return Container();
    })),
```

At the moment, this works just fine. **However, when I add in an AdMob advert the ad does not get a chance to load because `setState(() {})` within `takenSurvey2` seems to be rebuilding the app constantly, and I just see a flickering box.

How could I go about getting an update from Cloud Firestore about whether a user has taken the survey and if the value changes (i.e. they take the survey, or I change the current survey) the page is rebuilt or the icons change, rather than my current set up of constantly rebuilding the page with `setstate`.

Thank you. Sorry if this is not clear. I'm very new to coding.

Comment: i have are question are ads been loaded to your app from admob.. are you getting actual ads yet. Cause mine is not working last i checked

Comment: I'm using the test ads at the moment while I get everything set up - heard too many scare stories about AdMob being overzealous with punishing people for fake clicks.

Comment: yh heard about those to.. ok thanks

Answer (score 1):

hey the solution is a simple stream builder..

Stream builder will change what it returns without using setstate.. Anytime there is a change in the Current Survey document in Firebase

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('Controller')
      .document('Current Survey')
      .get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      print('Loading');
      //you can put a loadin widget here
    } else {
      var sn = snapshot.data;
      var surveyName = sn['cs'];
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection('$surveyName' + '_entrants')
            .document(userid)
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //this will check if it exists
            return Icon(
              Foundation.check,
              size: 48,
              color: Color(0xff303841),
            );
          } else {
            return Icon(
              Foundation.burst_new,
              size: 48,
              color: Color(0xff303841),
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm inserting it into my code (under the Positioned widget, correct?) and tt's returning one error - `error: The argument type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<dynamic>'.` Am I doing this right?

Comment: Excellent - do I replace the 'Future<void> takenSurvey2()' or the  'child: FutureBuilder('? I have replaced the latter and deleted the future void.

Comment: Replace everything you type.. Your whole code replace it with mine.. Try that.. You can later adjust the looks but replace the whole thing for now.. The way streams work is by getting the latest values always and using the values to determine what it shows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload a particular widget in the widget tree without rebuilding the scaffold, then I would suggest the use of ChangeNotifierProvider combined with a consumer applied only on the widget you want to reload when the provider updates

Reference: https://medium.com/flutterpub/provider-state-management-in-flutter-d453e73537c5